# layout 3 divs in a fixed containing div, with heights: 1div as much as it needs, 2div 60% from the rest, 3div 40% from the rest

Tags: html, css, layout

I tried doing this here http://jsfiddle.net/jhXuP/ but no luck,

I wan't to put 3 divs inside another one with defined height & width in px (which sometimes can change with js)

so I want the heights of the divs on the inside to be

1st - as much as it needs

2nd - 60% from the remaining space

3rd - 40% from the remaining space

anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution for this in css3. I created a demo for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/jhXuP/1/

The only problem is compatibility. So, you may consider checking if browser has support for flexible box module (name of the css3 goodness that allows us to do these adjustments) with [modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) and then if not, distribute the remaining height with javascript (would be easy with jquery).

Edit: I made a concept that also provides IE support for your speific case (has bugs and is just a starting point) - http://jsfiddle.net/jhXuP/2/